# Ghost in Python isn't taking full resolution browser screenshots

Tags: python, selenium, ghost

Windows 7/Python 2.6

I am trying to take full browser screenshots and then use pillow to compare the images. I have started to use Ghost for the screenshots because i couldn't seem to get Selenium/PhantomJS to take full browser screenshots in headless mode. When i take a screenshot using Ghost the resolution of the images are like 780x8000 even thought i set the viewport size to 1920x680 (just testing resolution sizes while getting use to pillow). Sadly i can't share the screenshots but here is just is a snippet of code.

```
from ghost import Ghost
self.ghost = Ghost(viewport_size=(1920,680))
self.ghost.open('someurl')
self.ghost.capture_to('somedir')
```

After taking the screenshot the image is showing all the items in the webpage, but at the 1000px wide breakpoint for the layout.

Can someone either explain how to get the desired results of getting screenshots at 1920x"PageHeight" using either ghost or possible some other python package?

Comment: With more investigation it seems like the maximum width it will go is 1260, but only if i set display=True in ghost. It isn't to much overhead but i would prefer to run this headless and have the ability to take 1920xPageHeight if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fix and it is to not set the viewport size in the constructor but using the set_viewport_size(x,y) method.

Comment: This however has not solved my problem of the page being extra long. When using Ghost the image is now 1920,6178 when the page on chrome is only ~2000px tall. Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: The way to solve this is to 
set_viewport_size(1920,0)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to take headless screenshots w/ selenium+phantomjs if you call

```
driver.set_window_size(x, y)
```

and then

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file( "/path/to/img.png" )
```